# How can I Install Python 2.6 in CentOs 7?

Tags: python, linux, centos7, python-2.6, epel

I Tried to install Python 2.6 in CentOs 7 with

```
sudo yum install python26
```

But, getting the following error.

> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks Loading mirror speeds from
>   cached hostfile  * base: centos.excellmedia.net  * epel:
>   kartolo.sby.datautama.net.id  * extras: centos.excellmedia.net  *
>   updates: centos.excellmedia.net No package python26 available. Error:
>       Nothing to do

I am also installed epel-release(sudo yum install epel-release) in CentOS 7. But, still the error is not resolved. Please help me.

Comment: Dare I ask - why do you need py2.6?

Comment: For building Ambari source. It requires python2.6 as prerequisite. So, I need this. cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Ambari+Development

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the RPM with the following command first:

```
rpm -Uvh https://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/epel/5/x86_64/python26-2.6.8-2.el5.x86_64.rpm
```

Then you can install it:

```
sudo yum install python26
```

Note that the newest version of EPEL doesn't support `python26` anymore, so you have to install it from the archive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, still following error is occurred. How can i overcome these.

Comment: warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.szdF0B: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 217521f6: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
 libcrypto.so.6()(64bit) is needed by python26-2.6.8-2.el5.x86_64
 libdb-4.3.so()(64bit) is needed by python26-2.6.8-2.el5.x86_64
 libffi.so.5()(64bit) is needed by python26-2.6.8-2.el5.x86_64
 libgdbm.so.2()(64bit) is needed by python26-2.6.8-2.el5.x86_64
 libpython2.6.so.1.0()(64bit) is needed by python26-2.6.8-2.el5.x86_64
 libreadline.so.5()(64bit) is needed by python26-2.6.8-2.el5.x86_64
 libssl.so.6()(64bit) is needed by python26-2.6.8-2.el5.x86_64
 libtermcap.so.